# Alter field value in a form

Tags: 8, forms

I've created a module so users can insert a link.

When users will insert their link, i wish to add a suffix to the link.

For exemple : they will add a link > "www.test.com"

I want to be able to add to the link once they hit save "http://"

So the link will be http://www.test.com

When i do :

```
$form['attributes']['href']['#prefix'] = 'prefix';
```

I get :
[image: prefix]

What's the best way to do it without using $form['attributes']['href']['#default_value']

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3):

As you want the suffix to be added when the save button is added you need to add a custom submit handler. In the `hook_form_alter` do something like       `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submit';` and in the submit function `mymodule_form_submit` save the value you want.

```
function mymodule_form_submit(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $entity = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  // Get the value of your field
  $my_val = $entity->get('field_name')->getValue();
  // Set new value
  $entity->set('field_name', 'http://' . $my_val);
  //Save the entity
  $entity->save();
}
```